# 404 Error with .htaccess Rewrite Rules on Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm facing an issue with URL rewriting on my Apache server and I'm hoping for some guidance. I'm trying to implement friendly URLs for a REST API, but I keep getting a 404 error.

**Setup:**

- Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
- URL trying to rewrite: http://test.com.br:8992/gmz/api/animal

**Objective:**
I want to access my animal.php script using the following URLs:

- http://test.com.br:8992/gmz/api/animal/(id)
- http://test.com.br:8992/gmz/api/animal

**Current .htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gmz/api/
RewriteRule ^animal/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ animal.php?search=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^animal/?$ animal.php [NC,L]
```

This file is located in /var/www/gmz/api/

**Steps Taken:**

- I've placed the .htaccess file in the same directory as animal.php.
- I've set AllowOverride All in my <Directory /var/www/gmz/api> directive within 000-default.conf.
- I've checked file permissions and ownership.
- I've restarted Apache after each change.

Despite these steps, trying to access http://test.com.br:8992/gmz/api/animal results in a 404 error.

**Additional Checks:**

- I confirmed that the mod_rewrite module is enabled.
- No relevant errors found in Apache's error logs.
- Testing with a simple rewrite rule also results in 404.

I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First of all, check if MultiViews is active - and if so, disable it, and see what you get then. (MultiViews can easily interfere in these type of situations, where you have a partial "overlap" between the fake URL you are requesting, and physically existing files.)

Comment: @CBroe 

Thank you for your suggestion. I followed your advice and disabled MultiViews in the Apache configuration for my /var/www/gmz/api directory. Here's what I added to my configuration file:

<Directory /var/www/gmz/api>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>



After making this change, I restarted the Apache server. Unfortunately, I'm still encountering the 404 error when trying to access

Comment: Then I would enable a bit of rewrite logging next - to verify whether this request goes through your rewrite setup at all to begin with, and if so, what exactly happens.